# Disable Storing of VPN Credentials

Tags: windows-10, vpn, group-policy

I am looking for a way to disable storing the VPN credentials for our clients. I have been looking through to find a GPO setting that will disable it but I have not been able to find one. Is there some option that allows me to disable this without disabling the user's ability to store domain credentials?

Comment: I think you need to search for such an option in the Settings of the VPN itself. What VPN are you using?

Comment: We are using the windows built in client. There is a checkbox that allows the user to store the credentials. We basically want to clear what they have and disable that box.